# Why is using an AST faster than not using one?

Tags: parsing, interpreter, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm making an interpreter for my own language as a hobby project. Currently my interpreter just executes the code as it sees it. I've heard you should make the parser generate an AST from the source code. So I was wondering, how does an AST actually make things faster than just executing the code linearly, as the parser sees it?

Comment: because if there's no data structure to represent your code, then you have to re-parse the source each time it's execute (e. g. in a loop).

Comment: It's not just for speed.  It's a lot easier to read and understand a traditional compiler/interpreter with separate lexical, parsing, and semantic phases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because then you would have to do the parsing all the time. If you have a loop for instance, you'd have to parse the commands in the loop body over and over again.

Also, I would argue that it's cleaner since you break down the problem in two distinct tasks: Deal with syntax, then deal with semantics.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't specifically the "AST" that makes it faster.

It is using any data structure (AST, symbol tables, control flow graph, triples, p-codes, machine code) that caches the analysis of source code to extract its intended meaning, and as much of precomputation of the answer ("optimization"), as possible.  In effect, anything that partially compiles the code, should produce programs that run faster than an interpreter of the pure text.

In interesting tradeoff: if the amount of program being executed before the execution stops isn't very big, it may actually be cheaper to execute the text, than to do any compiler-style analysis.

Given the speed of machines these days, one can sloppily compile a pretty big program in 100 milliseconds, which is about as fast as a human can react.  Various versions of TurboPascal back in the 80s and 90s were pretty famous for this.